# JavaScript click event Listener

Tags: javascript, click

I have a question.

```
btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  //////////
});
```

Is the above an example of an anonymous function?
And is there an es6 way syntax of writing it??

Comment: [Arrow function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) - although, personally, I like to just have a reference to the function there, and write the function separately elsewhere.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It's a function expression with no name, so yes, it is anonymous.

That syntax is ES6 (also ES5; ES6 is backwards compatible).